# Fenchel conjugate on a Hadamard manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, smooth-manifolds, convex-optimization

Let $M$ be a Hadamard manifold and let $F:M\to\mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued convex function on $M$. What would be the Fenchel-Young conjugate of $F$?

In general for a real locally convex vector space $V$ the Fenchel-Young conjugate (sometimes referred to as the Legendre transform) $F^*:V^*\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ of a functional (function, often convex) $F:V\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ (where $\overline{\mathbb{R}}:=\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$) is defined to be 
$$F^*(v^*):=\sup_{v\in V}\{(v^*,v)-F(v)\}, v^*\in V^*$$
Here $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$. However the last definition depends on the linear structure of $V$ and when $V=M$ we are not guaranteed such a structure.

Related is also the question of how to define a dual problem on a Hadamard manifold $M$ given an optimization problem (the primal problem) to solve. While there is extensive research on optimization problems on manifolds, I haven't been successful in finding works which deal particularly with the dual problems on manifolds. Is there current/previous research in this direction?

**Added:** Following Ferreira and Oliveira. Let $M$ be a Hadamard manifold and $F:M\to\mathbb{R}$ a convex real valued function on $M$. Let $x\in M$ and $TM_x$ be the tangent space at $x$. A vector $u\in TX_x$ is a subgradient of $F$ at $x$ whenever $$F(y)\geqslant F(x)+\langle u,\exp_x^{-1}y\rangle,\forall y\in M$$
where $\exp_x(\cdot):TM_x\to M$ is the exponential map and this is a global diffeomorphism (well known result due to Hadamard). The above definition coincides with the usual one when $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ since then $\exp_x^{-1}y=y-x$. Folowing the lines of the definition of the subgradient I tried to define "some" Fenchel conjuguate for our $F$ as follows. Since we need to work in a space with some linear structure a good candidate would be to use tangent spaces. For that we need to fix some $z\in M$ and its corresponding tangent space $TM_z$. Then define
$$F^*_z(u):=\sup_{y\in M}\{\langle u,\exp^{-1}_zy\rangle-F(y)\}$$
In the special case $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ it coincides with the shifted usual Fenchel conjugate in $\mathbb{R}^n$ i.e.
$$F^*_z(u)=F^*(u)-\langle u,z\rangle=(F(y+z))^*$$
Obviously the disadvantage is that the definition depends on $z$ hence pointwise. It is desirable of course to get a definition independent of $z$ so that the special case $\mathbb{R}^n$ is also recovered.

Comment: Isn't the conjugate the sup instead of the inf?

Comment: Yes, you are correct!

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.degruyter.com/view/product/428930?

Comment: Also, Movahedi, Mina; Behmardi, Daryoush; Hosseini, Seyedehsomayeh, [**On the density theorem for the subdifferential of convex functions on Hadamard spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.2015.276.437), Pac. J. Math. 276, No. 2, 437-447 (2015). [ZBL1321.53046](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1321.53046).

Comment: Maybe it would be best to study this on hyperbolic space first.

Comment: In Hadamard manifolds, $\exp_p :TM_p \to M $ is a diffeomorphism. So, one may consider  ($F\circ \exp_p)^*$ as a Fenchel conjugate of $F $.

Comment: @ChristianClason I have looked at Bacak's book but unfortunately (at least to my understanding) there is nothing related to dual problems/ Fenchel conjugate. Thanks for referring to the paper. But they just define the subgradient of a convex function on a Hadamard manifold and subsequently its subdifferential. However these concepts have been introduced, though in a different notation, by Ferreira and Oliveira earlier in their seminal paper https://orizon.mat.ufg.br/up/328/o/ProxPointMeth2.pdf. Still these definitions are not sufficient. I will add more details above what I have tried so far.

Comment: @Mahdi The problem is not which function to conjugate, in fact it is the linear structure of the space which for Hadamard spaces is not guaranteed.  We need somehow to rely on a space with linear structure (the best candidate would be the tangent space) but yet I am not fully satisfied with it. Please see my comments above.

Comment: One possible approach is to define convexity not as geodesic convexity but as horospherical convexity and use the space of Busemann functions as the "dual" space. But then it's not clear to me what the dual of the dual should be.

Comment: @Arian It really depends what you need the Fenchel conjugate for: often when you try to generalize a notion, you find that there are actually several related but *different* notions that just happen to coincide in the "easy" known case. If you are interested in optimization, the crucial property is that at a subdifferential, the Fenchel-Young inequality holds with equality. So the definition of the subdifferential should be taken as given, and the conjugate defined in such a way that the equality holds. (Also, it's difficult, which is why nobody has done it so far -- not for lack of trying ;))